# What software can I use to animate my character in Unity3D?

Tags: animation

I am new in game development and I want to know what software can help me to create good animations for my 3rd person character.

Comment: Are you asking about 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Most</strike> Many 3D modeling tools have animation capabilities. If you already have a model, find a tool such as Blender, 3D Max, Maya, etc. (the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software) goes on and on) that can open the respective format and you are ready to go. There are literally thousands of tutorials flying around that should teach you everything to get started in the respective program.

Regarding *good* animations: It highly depends and your capabilities and experience. With any of the commonly used tools great results can be achieved.

PS: Since you are just getting started, [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is probably your best bet, given that is does not cost any license fees. A good starting point would then be [this tutorial page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation). Additional Blender support can be found [here](http://www.blender.org/support/).

Comment: I would disagree with "most" but your point still stands, there are a lot of options.

Comment: @jhocking: Changed :) .